# Can I use the same preposition twice after the verb?

Tags: prepositions, is-it-a-rule, doubled-words

Can I use the same preposition twice after the verb?

For instance:

> the expectations provided **for for** the grade

Comment: There is only one preposition in *the expectations provided for **for** the upgrade*.  There is no preposition whatsoever in *to provide for*.

Comment: Yes. There's no grammatical bar on successive prepositions. However, OP could look for a better example because *provided for* is a phrasal verb as a whole, though technically it comprises of a verb and the preposition *for*.

Comment: @tchrist Just because it forms part of a phrasal verb, the *for* here does not cease to be a preposition by itself I think. See also my comment above.

Comment: @tchrist That's not correct. The phrase means "the expectations which were provided for". In that version of the sentence the object of the preposition is the word "which" - which then gets deleted along with "were" through whiz-deletion to give the OP's example. The notional object of the preposition here corresponds to "the expectations". Another way of looking at it is the Object of the preposition has become the notional Subject of a bare passive. Even in traditional grammar this would always be a preposition. Stranded prepositions are still prepositions in traditional analyses.

Comment: @Kris Where’d you dream that **up**? :)  Pretty sure *up* can’t be a preposition there.  *I’ll bet you dreamt it up down the lane*.  The little separable adverb attached to a regular verb to construct a phrasal verb isn’t acting like a preposition.

Comment: @tchrist Depends on whom you ask. If you ask Pullum et al., it's still a preposition, whether it has (or even can have) an object or not.

Comment: That said, the sentence fragment here makes absolutely no sense to me. How can expectations be provided for? Who is providing for them, and what are they providing them with to provide for them? And how can this be done for a grade?

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly grammatical to use two identical prepositions in a row. This will often happen when one of the prepositions has been stranded. This might be because the complement of the first preposition has become the subject of a passive clause:

- Four people had been booked in in August.

Here the notional object of the first *in* is *four people*, which has become the subject of this passive sentence. The second *in* is the head of a prepositional phrase, *in August*, which is functioning as a temporal adjunct in the sentence.

It is also common to have two identical prepositions when the complement of one of the prepositions has become embroiled in a relative clause:

- The guests whom you catered for for us, have written a very nice thank you letter.

In the sentence above the notional complement of the first *for* is the guests. [ More specifically,the phrase *the guests* serves as the antecedent for the relative pronoun *whom*, which in turn serves as the antecedent for the gap left by the missing complement of the word *for*.]

> the expectations provided for for the grade

In the Original Poster's example, we interpret the object of the first preposition to be *the expectations*. The phrase *provided for* is a participle construction with a passive interpretation modifying the noun *expectations*. The second *for* is the head of the preposition phrase *for the grade*, which functions as an adjunct (read "adverbial") in the sentence.

The Original Poster may be wondering if it is good *style* as opposed to good grammar to use sentences like this where there are two identical prepositions. The answer is that if it makes your reader double-take, it's probably not a good idea. But if it scans naturally, then it isn't a problem at all. You should let your internal ear make the decision.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on sentence. I don't have great grammatical knowledge,but found a reference page about repetition of words:-

http://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-to-do-when-words-appear-twice-in-a-row/

Any way, there is always a chance to simplify your sentence to a avoid repetition of words.

```
What it is, is a travesty!?
She gives in in every case.
We realize that that will not be satisfactory.
```

**Simpler form:-**

```
What it is. . . is a travesty.?
She always gives in.
We realize that will not be satisfactory.
```

Comment: Rephrasing is not an answer :)

Comment: Thanks you all for your input. Most enlightening. It is not really a good phrase, it's not wrong but it is kind of awkward and could be made a lot simpler.  Thanks agains.